# How can I handle a dynamic viewModel in my controller?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, dynamicobject

In my controller, my create method takes a viewModel that inherits from DynamicObject. The reason is that I need static properties on the model, but I may also add things to it via JavaScript before I pass it to the controller.

So, I have:

```
public class MyViewModel: DynamicObject {
    public string id {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create(MyViewModel viewModel) {
    // save to Db
}
```

From the JavaScript (using Angular), I've passed in this viewmodel:

```
var vm = { id: 1, name: "Jim"};
```

However, this does not work and is throwing me this error:

```
[{"PropertyName":null,"ErrorMessage":null,"ErrorCode":null,"AttemptedValue":null,"CustomState":null}]
```

I haven't found an example of what I'm trying to do, but I would think making an object dynamic would allow for this. What am I missing here?

Comment: It should work without any issue as long as properties within the dynamic object matches.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota I don't think that's correct. The entire purpose of it being dynamic is that the C# view model doesn't know ahead of time what properties it's going to have. If I had to declare them, that wouldn't make it very dynamic.

Comment: The model binder fails because it tries to either use a constructor with the key value pair or reflect properties of the view model with the key value pair. Neither of which are present for `name`, and as a result the key value pair is not bound to the model.

Comment: @TravisJ That makes sense. So, is there any way around this?

Comment: @Yatrix - Not that I am aware of. There may be, but I have not used such an open ended approach before. If there were a way to send it to be deserialized with some information about the key structure, or perhaps if you sent additional information for reflection. I tend to stick to hard coded view models.

Comment: I am a little off-topic and my mvc is rusty, but I remember struggling for days to no avail in mvc 3 to get views working with less concrete models (generics, derived classes, interfaces), back then I had a specific scenario in mind with one complicated control that should be used in the same way in many places on the site, and I tried to reuse one view that contained that control. Long story short: use partial views for the various scenarios. Don't use complicated viewmodels. If you want dynamic properties use the ViewBag... yuck

Comment: @NamelessOne I think you can pass in an ExpandoObject and go that route, but it doesn't look like there's a good way to do what I'm trying. You'd think if the object was dynamic, it would be able to handle that